# Adding another object inside an existing JSON

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm basically trying to save data into a json,

so basically:

```
{
"userid1": {
    "name" : "user1",
    "wins" : "21",
    "loss" : "0",
    "leaderboard" : "1"
},
"userid2": {
    "name" : "user2",
    "wins" : "0",
    "loss" : "0",
    "leaderboard" : "0"
},
// how do you push another object, let's say; this time; userid3 which would look like this. 

// "userid3": {
//  "name" : "user3",
//  "wins" : "0",
//  "loss" : "0",
//  "leaderboard" : "0"
// }

// (using javascript, from another file; let's say it's called "datasave.js") 
// here?
}
```

I want to add another object instead of rewriting the whole thing. How do I do that?

This is a json file on it's own, there's another .js file and that's where the json file gets parsed. I want to add the object from there.

I've got it working somehow now. imgur.com/zQTJ11K; there's a var called "id" and that id's the userId, how do I change the "id" in the picture to the userId?

Comment: Image doesn't "says it all".  Post your code as text.

Comment: `data.userid3 = { /* Your new object here */}`

Comment: Robby, let's say that userid3 doesn't exist, how do we make it exist?

Comment: If it doesn’t exist, it will create it, if it does exist it will override it

Comment: that's not JSON by the way - if it were JSON, you'd have to parse it, add the new entry, and stringify it to make it JSON again

Comment: i think some of you are mistaken, this is a json file on it's own, there's another .js file and that's where the json file gets parsed. I want to change the content from there

Answer (score 0):

```js
output = {
  "userid1": {
      "name" : "user1",
      "wins" : "21",
      "loss" : "0",
      "leaderboard" : "1"
  },
  "userid2": {
      "name" : "user2",
      "wins" : "0",
      "loss" : "0",
      "leaderboard" : "0"
  }
};

u3 = {
        "name" : "user2",
        "wins" : "0",
        "loss" : "0",
        "leaderboard" : "0"
     };
          
output.userid3 = u3;

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I've got it working somehow now. https://imgur.com/zQTJ11K; there's a var called "id" and that id's the userId, how do I change the "id" in the picture to the userId?

Comment: found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
const result = Object.assign(data, objToAdd);
```

Or [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

```
data['userId3'] = obj
```

Or dot notation

```
data.userId3 = obj
```

```js
const data = {
  "userid1": {
    "name": "user1",
    "wins": "21",
    "loss": "0",
    "leaderboard": "1"
  },
  "userid2": {
    "name": "user2",
    "wins": "0",
    "loss": "0",
    "leaderboard": "0"
  }
}

const obj = {
  "userid3": {
    "name": "user3",
    "wins": "0",
    "loss": "0",
    "leaderboard": "0"
  }
}

Object.assign(data, obj);

console.log(data)
```

Comment: this is a json file on it's own, there's another .js file and that's where the json file gets parsed. I want to add the object from there.

Answer (score -1):

you can [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) another file into your file using js import.you can import your objects too

you can use javascript [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to combine two objects into one

```
var object1={name:"xyz"}
var object2={surname:"abc"}
then object1={...object1,...object2} // object={name:"xyz",surname:"abc"}
```